# how to apply a filter for an attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help solve the problem.

I write custom filter for text. in first case i output myText and apply filter, result is OK

html:

```
<div ng-app="main4">
  <md-content ng-controller="main4Ctrl">
    <h2 class="md-display-1 ng-binding">Главная страница 3</h2>

    <sapn id="firstCase">{{myText | transform}}</sapn> - it worked
    <hr>
    <span id="secondCase" ng-bind-html="myText"/>      - but it not worked
  </md-content>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('main4', [])
.controller('main4Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myText = 'qWeRtYuIoP';
  }
]).filter('transform',[function(){
  return function(text){
    return transformTetx = text.toLowerCase();
  }
}]);
```

I need apply this filter for second case

[JSFILLDE](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lhjeqv4/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need `angular sanitize` in order to use `ng-bind-html`

```
angular.module('main4', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('main4Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myText = 'qWeRtYuIoP';
  }
]).filter('transform',[function(){
  return function(text){
    return transformTetx = text.toLowerCase();
  }
}]);

<span id="secondCase" ng-bind-html="myText | transform"></span>
```

**I have updated your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/5Lhjeqv4/5/)**

Make sure that you use the same version of `angular-sanitize.js` as of the `angular.js`. This is very important

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply your filter from your controller, you can do the following:

Inject the `$filter` service and call it by using

```
var transformedData = $filter('transform')(dataToTransform);
```

or

You can inject `transformFilter` into your controller and directly use it.

```
var transformedData2 = transformFilter(dataToTransform);
```

Angular will automatically recognize that `transform` is a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-bind on the span element instead. Here's the working fiddle

```
 <div ng-app="main4">
   <md-content ng-controller="main4Ctrl">
   <span id="firstCase">{{myText | transform}}</span> - it worked
   <hr>
   <span id="secondCase" ng-bind="myText | transform"></span>     - but it not worked
</div>

var app = angular.module('main4', []);
app.controller('main4Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout',
   function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
     $scope.myText = 'qWeRtYuIoP';
   }
])
app.filter('transform',[function(){
    return function(text){
        return transformTetx = text.toLowerCase();
    }
}]);
```